# Cannot show data to chart - 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to showing chart from json data , i'm using `charts_flutter: ^0.7.0` .

Here is my json

```
[
    {
        "tanggal": 1,
        "total": 1677765
    },
    {
        "tanggal": 2,
        "total": 0
    },
    {
        "tanggal": 3,
        "total": 779920
    },
]
```

here is what i do

```
FutureBuilder(
                        future: _getData(),
                        builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
                          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting &&
                              snapshot.hasError == false) {
                            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                          } another condition
                           else {
                            return new charts.PieChart(
                                dataList(snapshot.data),
                                defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(
                                    arcRendererDecorators: [new charts.ArcLabelDecorator()])
                            );
                          }

                        }
                    ),
```

then here is `_getData()` and where i try to build my chart

```
_getData(String tahun, String bulan, String Outlet) async{
    final response = await http.get(Configuration.url + "api/cartData/"+tahun+"/"+bulan+"/"+Outlet);
    print(Configuration.url + "api/cartData/"+tahun+"/"+bulan+"/"+Outlet);
    Map<dynamic,dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
    return map;
  }

  static List<charts.Series<LinearSales, int>> dataList(Map<dynamic, dynamic> apiData) {
    List<LinearSales> list = new List();
    for(int i=0; i<apiData.length; i++)
      list.add(new LinearSales(i, apiData[i]));
    return [
      new charts.Series<LinearSales, int>(
        id: 'Sales',
        domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.day,
        measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: list,
        labelAccessorFn: (LinearSales row, _) => '${row.day}: ${row.sales}',
      )
    ];
  }
```

But when i run it i get this

> type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map'

How can i fix it ? did i miss something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
 Map<dynamic,dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
```

into this:

```
 Iterable data = json.decode(response.body);
 List<dynamic> list = data.toList();
```

Then change this:

```
  static List<charts.Series<LinearSales, int>> dataList(Map<dynamic, dynamic> apiData) {
```

into this:

```
  static List<charts.Series<LinearSales, int>> dataList(List<dynamic> apiData) {
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, now i get this error type `'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'int'`

Comment: on which line do u get this?

Comment: Hi, i already fix it , i change `list.add(new LinearSales(i, apiData[i]));` to `list.add(new LinearSales(apiData[i]['tanggal'], apiData[i]['total']));`

Comment: yes since this is alist of objects first bracket will contain the index and second bracket will contain the attribute name